# Django Queryset Design: Filtering out soft-deleted users?

Tags: python, django

I have a soft-delete user model in Django, where we set `is_active` to False.

But one problem I'm running into is needing to filter out `is_active` users on every type of content:

- `Item.objects.filter(user__is_active=False, ...)`
- `Comment.objects.filter(user__is_active=False, ...)`
- `User.objects.filter(is_active=False, ...)`

And so-on. Is there some type of Django / Pythonic design pattern I can use here to avoid needing to manually filter out all users every time I query something made by a user, or a current list of users?

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/

You need to use custom managers and add to model.
You can redefine `get_queryset` method to filter is_active.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ModelManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/).

For example:

```
class ItemManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    .....
    objects = ItemManager() # your custom manager
    all_objects = models.Manager() # default manager
```

Now with `Item.objects.all()` you will get objects having `is_active=True` only.

If you want all the objects then you can use `Item.all_objects.all()`